# Google Developers Console - Duplicate Fingerprint

Tags: android, google-console-developer

I have 2 projects that were in the hands of another team, I was trying to create a OAuth 2.0 client ID for Android and it fails because probably someone already created it in another Google Console Project. It's impossible to contact the previous owners of the Project for lack of knowledge/will of resolving the situation.

The error given is the following:

> Duplicate fingerprint The fingerprint you specified is already used by
>   an Android OAuth 2.0 client ID in this project or another project

Seeing that the Apps are already in the Store I can't simply change the package or the keystore to make it work.

Anyone with a similar problem that managed to reach a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by entering into contact with the Google Cloud Platform Support [in the forums](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/).

Afterwards they managed to find who had the duplicate fingerprint and I managed to enter into contact with the specific person so they deleted the old project and everything was now working on my end.

(I know it was an old problem and I solved it some months ago but I noticed on my account that it was going unsolved. So I'm just posting this to see if it's able to help anyone else.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help somebody.

After getting this error I spent 4 hours checking all my accounts, all projects in them and than checking it again. I have even asked all developers in my team if they had created any keys for our package name. Finally I have found a project hidden on "All projects" tab containing the client id I was searching for.

Comment: thank you for this.  Probably would have spent several more hours looking if you didn't write this